# Process.Start() fails for *.jpg-Files

Tags: c#, .net, windows, process, process.start

I use the following code to open `jpg`-files:

```
var file = @"C:\Users\administrator.ADSALL4SPS\Desktop\IMG_4121.JPG";
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { Verb = "open", FileName = file };
var workDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workDir)) {
    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workDir;
}
try {
    Process.Start(processStartInfo);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // Errorhandling
}
```

Now, when I do this, I get always an Win32Exception with `NativeErrorCode = ERR_NO_ASSOCIATION`

But the extension `*.jpg` is associated to MSPaint.

When I double click the File then the File is opened in MSPaint.

Why is there a `Win32Exception` even the file is associated?

Comment: Is this a windows application ?

Comment: Yes - its a WindowsApplication (.NET 4 with winforms)

Comment: Do you want to use picturebox?

Comment: I want to open the jpg-file with the default-windows-application (like MSPaint).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible that the JPG extension doesn't have an explicit ***open*** verb registered for it, in which case you can omit it and the underlying [`ShellExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) function will use the first registered verb (which, in your case, may be ***edit***):

```
    var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo { FileName = file };
```

The [`ProcessStartInfo.Verbs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.verbs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property contains all the registered verbs for the given file name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
        string file = @"C:\Users\administrator.ADSALL4SPS\Desktop\IMG_4121.JPG";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(file);
```

Because you want to open this file with default windows application you need to use `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` to open files with default applications.

Comment: This looks almost the same as what they did in the question, they just used the overload that takes a ProcessStartInfo instead of just the string.  Same thing, right?

Comment: @MobyDisk No. They are different. Read the code again you'll see difference between them. The user tried to use `Verb`, However I didn't use this at all. And this answer is only two lines of codes which can be written even with one line so it's better and gives better compiling time.